# SELECT nidificate with UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute this query, the error result is:

> The multi-part identifier "table2.column1" could not be bound.

Do I have to use an `INNER JOIN`? If yes, where?

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.column1 = 1 
WHERE table1.column2 = 'Example' 
  AND table2.column1 = (SELECT table2.column1  
                        FROM table2 
                        WHERE table2.column2 = 'anotherExample');
```

Thank you and sorry for my english (I'm Italian).

Comment: You require an `UPDATE FROM` statement, but this itself requires an inner join between table1 and table2 as you say. What is the relationship between table1 and table2? i.e. does one have a foreign key relationship to the other?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And, what is "nidificate" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Wibbler . . . `UPDATE . . . FROM` is only allowed in some databases.  It is just one of many possible solutions, depending on information not currently in the question.

Comment: Hence the need to clarify questions before submitting answers to them.

Comment: @Wibbler you are right

Comment: Nidificate:  To make or build a nest (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nidificate)

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with inner join, it's easier

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.column1 = 1 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
    WHERE t1.column2='Example' 
          AND t2.column2 = 'anotherExample';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET table1.column1 = 1 
    WHERE table1.column2 = 'Example' AND
          table2.column1= (SELECT table2.column1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.column2 = 'anotherExample');
----------^
```

I assume you want something from `table1` here:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET table1.column1 = 1 
    WHERE table1.column2 = 'Example' AND
          table1.columnX = (SELECT table2.column1
                            FROM table2
                            WHERE table2.column2 = 'anotherExample');
```

Your SQL is actually standard SQL and should work in any database.

Comment: There would seem to be a bout of malicious downvoting.

Comment: @dizero has specified no relationship between table1 and table2

Comment: @Wibbler . . . Perhaps in another question?  I see no such statement in this question or comments.

Comment: @Gordin Linoff I apologise for not being clear, dizero hasn't said how table1 and table2 join together. There are three answers here assuming what the relationship between those tables is.

Comment: @Wibbler . . . This answer is pointing out why the OP is getting an error and a very reasonable way to fix it without using `JOIN`.  Presumably, there is a relationship between the tables, or one would not be used to update the other.

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't explain that to him. He has stated he doesn't know what the join should be, perhaps some clarification in your answer as to what `columnX` should be replaced by?